# Prove polynomial generates vector space, but it's not linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

$$ S = (1, 2x + 3, x^3, −1 + x^2, x^2)$$
How to prove this polynomial is not linear independence, but it generates vector space? I thought it means it's linear dependent => but it can't generates vector space. So for me it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: $1+(-1+x^2)=x^2$

Comment: Write the elements of $S$ in the standard basis and row reduce.

Comment: A faster way to know that they are not linearly independent than finding the explicit collection that violates it... there are *five* vectors given here... but we know that $P_3$, the space of polynomials whose degree is at most three (*some authors use $P_4$ instead*) is a *four-dimensional space*.  Five vectors in a four dimensional space, or more generally $n$ vectors in an $m$ dimensional space where $n>m$, will always be linearly dependent.

Comment: Linear dependence does *not* by itself mean that the space cannot be generated by them.  That just means that they do not form a basis.  The reason that it fails to be a basis is because it fails to be linearly independent.  The second part of being a basis, being able to span the desired space, on the other hand is not directly affected by whether or not the set is dependent.  We *prefer* bases to generate spaces with since we will have a unique representation in terms of basis elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the linear dependency, I see the comment answered it. I hope is clear.
In regards to possible base, first it refers to the vector space of polynomials of degree up to 3.

Any polynomial of degree 3 or less can be generated using 4 of the 5 given vectors:

$a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0= a_3(x^3-1)+a_2(x^2-1)+\frac{a_1}{2}(2x+3)+(a_0 +a_3+a_2-\frac{3}{2}a_1)\cdot 1$